# Error while trying to connect to Octobercms database: Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: octobercms

I keep getting this error on my server:

```
Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

There is a problem with the specified Database configuration. My host is TSDhost.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What database driver are you using? MySQL? SQLite?

Comment: check your port number.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution would be to set the database host from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`